# How to install an app to only one user in Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint

Anyone please tell me How to install an app to only one user in Linux Mint?
If I install any app from websites like telegram or from  software centre,
Those apps get installed in both users.
How to install it for only one user?

Comment: What "app" are you talking about? How are you trying to install it? Edit your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2):

Generally if you install then the binaries will install to as an example /usr or /bin i.e. some folder that is in the path for all users. Any personalisation for each user for that binary is stored in their home folder often in a hidden folder i.e. program name prefixed by a period.

To be installed for a single user then install the binary using that account and not elevating with sudo to the users home folder.

if you explain exactly which app you are tying to install then maybe advice can be more specific and less generic.